# "Python NameError: name is not defined" for class

Tags: python

I am having difficulty fully defining the Questions class in my Python code.  I have played around with it, but have had no luck.

```
import sys
import random


class Question():
    def __init__(self, ques, pa1, pa2, pa3, pa4, correct):
        self._q = ques
        self._pa1 = pa1
        self._pa2 = pa2
        self._pa3 = pa3
        self._pa4 = pa4
        self._correct = correct

    def get_ques(self):
        return self._q
    def get_pa1(self):
        return self._pa1
    def get_pa2(self):
        return self._pa2
    def get_pa3(self):
        return self._pa3
    def get_pa4(self):
        return self._pa4
    def get_correct(self):
        return self._correct


    def main():
        lst_ques = [
            Question("What is our nation's capital", 3, ["Texas", "Virginia", "Washington, D.C.", "New York"]),
            Question("How many burrows make up New York city", 4, ["two", "four", "three", "five"]),
            Question("In what month does the leap year occur", 1, ["February", "July", "December", "October"]),
            Question("What state do the Cowboys football team play for", 2, ["New York", "Texas", "California", "Utah"]),
            Question("What's the symbol to Iron", 1 ,["Fe", "Ie", "Ir", "In"]),
            Question("Where is Notre Dame", 4 ,["Michigan", "Japan", "Ireland", "France"]),
            Question("About how many billion years old is the sun", 3 ,["1", "4", "5", "2"]),
            Question("What's the most malleable metal", 2 ,["iron", "gold", "aluminum", "steel"]),
            Question("What is short for binary digit", 2 ,["bd", "bit", "bin", "digit"]),
            Question("What is the Indiana state bird", 4 ,["robin", "eagle", "finch", "cardinal"]),
                ]
        print('Player #1, please begin.')
        i = 1
        ca1 = 1
        ques_attempted = []
        while i<=5:
            number = random.radiant(0,9)
            if number not in ques_attempted:
                print('Question',i)
                print(lst_ques[number].get_ques())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa1())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa2())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa3())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa4())
                answer = input('Enter in correct answer: ')
                if ques[number].get_correct()==int(ans):
                    print('Correct!')
                    ca1+=1
                else:
                    print('Incorrect')
                    ques_attempted.append(number)
                    i+= 1
                    print('Player #2, it is now your turn, please begin.')
                    i = 1
                    ca2 = 1
                    ques_attempted = []
                while i<=5:
                    number = random.radiant(0,9)
                    if number not in ques_attempted:
                       print('Question',i)
                print(lst_ques[number].get_ques())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa1())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa2())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa3())
                print(lst_ques[number].get_pa4())
                answer = input('Enter in correct answer: ')
                if ques[number].get_correct()==int(ans):
                    print("Correct!")
                    i = 1
                    ca2+=1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
            ques_attempted.append(number)
            print('The final scores are: ')
            print('Player #1: ', ca1)
            print('Player #2: ', ca2)
        if ca1 > ca2:
            print('Player #1 is the winner.')
        elif ca2 > ca1:
            print('Player #2 is the winner.')
        else:
            print('The final scores are the same, the game is a tie.')

    main()
```

It's throwing the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Question():
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 94, in Question
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 30, in main
    Question("What is our nation's capital", 3, ["Texas", "Virginia", "Washington, D.C.", "New York"]),
NameError: name 'Question' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is that exception thrown?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy: isn't it obvious :) - at the line `code here` at the end!

Comment: `number = random.radiant(0,9)` should be `number = random.randint(0,9)`

Comment: It looks like it is throwing it at line 5...at the class Question.

Comment: BTW your code is terrible, there are big parts of completelly same code. Also `main()` (on the almost last line) is on the wrong indentation level (as a class method).

Comment: The full error is below

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Question():
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 94, in Question
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Documents\Lindsay's Files\Python_TEST.py", line 30, in main
    Question("What is our nation's capital", 3, ["Texas", "Virginia", "Washington, D.C.", "New York"]),
NameError: name 'Question' is not defined

Comment: Please don't use comments, add it to your question (and format it properly).

Comment: I apologize, I am VERY new at Python.  I've been emailing my instructor...but haven't received any replies.

Comment: I changed the randint problem.  I just didn't see that before.

Comment: @Natecat Not if the OP wants a random glow! =D

Answer (score 5):

It's simple. You have defined the `main` as a `Question` class' method, but I guess it should be just a function, so move it one indentation level to the left and it's fixed.

So it should look like this:

```
class Question:
    def __init__():
    # other methods

def main():
    # code

main()
```

**Explanation:** In your code, you define the `main` as a `Question` class' method and also you execute it inside the class before it's defined, that's why are you getting the `NameError` exception `'Question' is not defined`.

```
class Question():
    def main(): # here you define main as Question's method
        # some code

    main() # here you're executing the main method before Question's definition is finished
```

Comment: Okay, I did that.  Now I am getting the error...TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'pa3', 'pa4', and 'correct'.

Comment: And which part of that exception don't you understand? I think it's pretty clear and obvious. You defined Question's constructor with 6 arguments, but you're calling it with 3 arguments only.

Comment: @LinzG the thing is that the definition of your class and how you call it don't mach, with the current definition I think that you want to call it as `Question("What's the symbol to Iron", "Fe", "Ie", "Ir", "In",1)`

Comment: I think I understand how I need to fix this.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @LinzG Did my answer help you to solve your problem? If yes, please accept it, so others can more easily find the answer.